# Django Live data view to web page

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-views

I want to display the csv data to web page. The data from the csv is live which means the continuously added to the csv. Meanwhile the webpage needs to display the updated data as well. How can i do that? The csv file located in the local machine.

Answer (score 1):

You will need some sort of database/DBMS to handle the live connection. Since a CSV is a static file on your computer, it won't directly update your django view.

The way I do it is make a small tkinter programme on my local computer that pushes the CSV to Postgresql or a DBMS of your choice. The app pushes the updated file to the database which is directly updated in Django.